Moving packages on a grid to accommodate additional packages
The Problem
I need to pack the maximum number of packages on a 2 dimensional grid. Think of a chess / checkers like grid. One square can only accommodate one package.
The packages come in groups of 3 to 8, and have some requirements:

The group has to be completely placed on the grid (partial placement is not an option)
There is a required pattern for each group. The requirement tells you how many sub-groups the packages need to go in, the size of each sub-group and the minimum "gap" between sub-groups.

I have an existing solution in place which "molds" the incoming groups based on the space available. That approach works very well until I get to the end. Which is where I need some help devising an algo.
An Example
Let's say this is the current state of the grid. The existing packages all satisfy their respective constraints. Now I need to place a group of 3 pieces in 2 sub-groups with a minimum gap of 2 (something like 2,0,0,1). I can obviously not place the incoming group on this grid.
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X . . . X X

I could move the existing pieces to make room like this:
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X . X X X X X
X . X X . X X

Or this
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X . . X X .

Or this
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
. X X X X X X
. X X X X X .

There are of course many combinations that would work. I just need to get to one of them.
The Ask
I would love to know if this is (or can be modeled as) a well known problem with a known solution. But I'll take any logic that works. It is desirable to move as few pieces as possible, but I don't need the "best possible" option. "Good enough" would do.

It is confusing that apparently the starting position already violates the rule. Obviously no gaps are present in most of the rows, so how did those pieces even get there without violating the rule? Also, how did you decide to pick those two pieces to be moved, and not one of the seemingly thousands of other possibilities to take pieces from?

Sorry, I've edited the question to clarify. Basically the constraints apply within the "group" only. The problem is to place many groups on the board.

Too many loose ends for me. I'll leave this for someone else to look at.

I find it impossible to understand the question.  You mention a chess board.  Are the "pieces" the usual chess pieces with their usual movement rules? They do not seem to be!  Are the "rules" part of the input, possible different on each run?  Is there any limit on what the 'rules' can be?  It might help to add a concrete example with complete input and expected result.

Your example shows an 7 by 6 grid.  So, it is NOT a chess board!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

"All the existing pieces have their own rules to move." This suggests that there is a starting configuration (which might be unacceptable), and then you "move" the pieces to new positions to reach another possibly unacceptable configuration, repeating until you reach an acceptable configuration. So it is not a combinatorial enumeration problem due to the sequencing requirements.

@ravenspoint. You're correct, it is not a chess board and I am not trying to put chess pieces on the board. I was using that to help visualize, but obviously it caused confusion. I've updated the language to "grid"

@RaymondChen. I've removed the language about rules for existing pieces. I can handle that outside of the context of the question I am asking. I just need help identifying which pieces to move in which direction so that the empty squares can accommodate the incoming group. The starting position is never unacceptable.

You say that there are "some basic rules", but only tell us one of them. Please copy-paste the full and complete assignment or exercise, so we have all rules, requirements and limitations.

In "tetris" the player knows only what the next incoming piece is.  How about here?  Can the algorithm look ahead to consider all the pieces that will 'arrive'?  As @trincot says, there are way too many loose ends in this question.

No look aheads, and no "discarding" the piece. (it's not a game, but a part of a real world optimization problem).

So remove the tetris reference and explain your problem completely.  ( If you keep referencing games ( chess, tetris ) then you must expect people to think this is a game also )

My best guess is that this is a bin packing problem.  ( Can't be sure since so many details are missing ).  There are lots of bin packing algorithms available on the web.  However, I am unaware of any that handle such awkward item shapes.  Bin packing regular shaped items is already a significant challenge.  This will be truly hard to solve with anything better than a rough approximation.  Would you accept such?

@ravenspoint. That's a fair point about games. I've restated the problem to remove game references. Hopefully it causes less confusion. Just knowing that standard problems / algos don't have a straightforward solution here is already helpful for me. Rough approximations is probably the best I can hope for.

Sorry.  My bin packing suggestions are mistaken.  Since there are no look aheads then bin packing does not apply.  I misread your comment, sorry.

What exactly is allowed as a possible movement?  Can you lift a combination of pieces of the board, "mold" it into a different shape, rotate it and then place it back down anywhere on the board that does not collide with other pieces.  Can you lift several groups of the board, mold and rotate them, and place them back in a new arrangement?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

" I just need help identifying which pieces to move..." My point is that talking about "moving" pieces implies that you need to "perform a sequence of moves" to reach an acceptable state. By "perform a move" I mean "you have an existing state, and there are rules specifying what changes to the state are permitted." This is different from just placing items and determining whether they satisfy certain constraints (which is stateless). Is the question stateful or stateless?

@RaymondChen. Ok, I think I get your point. My real packing problem is stateful, and there are other complexities that I've tried to keep out of this problem statement. The way I have stated the problem, I simply need a solution that says something like "move one package from column 0 to column 2, and one package from column 1 to column 3 and you have a viable shape to accommodate the incoming group".

A 2D repeating bin packing problem with items that are the bounding rectangles of the groups, performing a new pack for each arrival but minimizing movement of previously packed rectangles.
In more detail:

A group arrives
Calculate bounding rectangle
IF rectangle fits into empty space

place rectangle into space
update empty space
wait for next group arrival


LOOP
Unpack most recent previous packed rectangle
IF new arrival and unpacked rectangles fit into empty space

place groups into space, recording moves for unpacked rectangle
update empty space
break from loop


ENDLOOP
wait for next group arrival

